# Implementing RC4 on Racket

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, racket, rc4-cipher

I'm trying to translate a C# implementation of the RC4 cipher I wrote to the Racket language.

However, they are producing different keystreams. I have already eliminated the possiblity of miswriting the key-scheduling phase; that must be correct as they result in the same array `S`. Thus I'm focusing on finding differences in the keystream generation phase.

C#:

```
public int Dencode (int c)
{
    I = (I + 1) % 256;
    J = (J + S [I]) % 256;
    int tmp = S [I];
    S [I] = S [J];
    S [J] = tmp;
    return S [(S[I] + S[J]) % 256] ^ c;
}
```

Racket:

```
(define (toret c)
    (set! i (unsafe-fxmodulo (add1 i) 256))
    (set! j (unsafe-fxmodulo (add1 (Sr i)) 256))
    (swap! (box (Sr i)) (box (Sr j)))
    (bitwise-xor (Sr (unsafe-fxmodulo (+ (Sr i) (Sr j)) 256)) c))
```

with `swap` defined as

```
(define (swap! ba bb)
  (define temp (unbox ba))
  (set-box! ba (unbox bb))
  (set-box! bb temp))
```

and `Sr` defined as `(define (Sr x) (unsafe-bytes-ref S x))`.

What is the difference? Why are these functions producing different output? In both cases `i` and `j` are initialized to 0, and `S` is an identical 256-byte array.

Comment: What does this have to do with the C++ tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a very stupid error. `(set! j (unsafe-fxmodulo (add1 (Sr i)) 256))` is not equivalent to `J = (J + S [I]) % 256;`! Adding debug printf lines after each statement helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
(swap! (box (Sr i)) (box (Sr j)))
```

won't do what you expect. It doesn't magically make `(Sr i)` and `(Sr j)` mutable references. The `swap!` procedure swaps the contents of the boxes---but the boxes contain `(Sr i)` and `(Sr j)` by value, not by reference.

What you need to do is to amend your `swap!` procedure to use `unsafe-bytes-set!` instead.

---

Here's some code to demonstrate my point:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/unsafe/ops)

(define (box-swap! x y)
  (define tmp (unbox x))
  (set-box! x (unbox y))
  (set-box! y tmp))

(define (wrong-swap! bs x y)
  (box-swap! (box (unsafe-bytes-ref bs x))
             (box (unsafe-bytes-ref bs y))))

(define (right-swap! bs x y)
  (define tmp (unsafe-bytes-ref bs x))
  (unsafe-bytes-set! bs x (unsafe-bytes-ref bs y))
  (unsafe-bytes-set! bs y tmp))
```

Example:

```
> (define bs (bytes 1 2 3 4 5 6))
> bs
#"\1\2\3\4\5\6"
> (wrong-swap! bs 0 5)
> bs
#"\1\2\3\4\5\6"
> (right-swap! bs 0 5)
> bs
#"\6\2\3\4\5\1"
```

Comment: It does work per my tests. `S` is a `bytes` type, not a `vector` type. Anyways, I found my error.

Comment: @EricDong You've found one error, not the only error. You still need to reformulate your `swap!` to use `unsafe-bytes-set!`; your use of boxes is still incorrect (and turns the `swap!` call into an effective no-op).

Comment: Make no mistake: all your `S[x] = y;` statements _must_ eventually turn into `unsafe-bytes-set!` calls. Using boxes won't get around that requirement.